# Rails Internationalization (I18n): locale in the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I'm new to rails (using 3.2.1) and I was following the i18n-guide on [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

I'm having problems with this section:

> You probably want URLs to look like this: www.example.com/en/books
>   (which loads the English locale) and www.example.com/nl/books (which
>   loads the Netherlands locale). This is achievable with the
>   “over-riding default_url_options” strategy from above: you just have
>   to set up your routes with path_prefix option in this way

But when I use <%= products_path %> in my views, it returns: **/products?locale=en**
and I want it to return **/nl/products**

When I type an url in the browser (f.e. localhost:3000/nl/products) the page displays the correct locale.

What am I missing?

Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def default_url_options(options = {})
    { :locale => I18n.locale }
  end
end
```

routes:

```
  scope "/:locale" do
    resources :products
  end

  match '/:locale' => 'products#index'
```

rake routes:

```
    products GET    /products(.:format)                  products#index
             POST   /products(.:format)                  products#create
 new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)              products#new
edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)         products#edit
     product GET    /products/:id(.:format)              products#show
             PUT    /products/:id(.:format)              products#update
             DELETE /products/:id(.:format)              products#destroy
             GET    /:locale/products(.:format)          products#index
             POST   /:locale/products(.:format)          products#create
             GET    /:locale/products/new(.:format)      products#new
             GET    /:locale/products/:id/edit(.:format) products#edit
             GET    /:locale/products/:id(.:format)      products#show
             PUT    /:locale/products/:id(.:format)      products#update
             DELETE /:locale/products/:id(.:format)      products#destroy
                    /:locale(.:format)                   products#index
        root        /                                    products#index
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [rails-translate-routes gem](https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes).

It gave me the expected result + it's possible to translate the routes which is a great surplus.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the `path_prefix` option instead

```
def default_url_options(options = {})
  { :path_prefix => I18n.locale }
end
```

Comment: Using path_prefix displays the url as /products?path_prefix=nl